# Is there a way to know if a field extends java.awt.Component?

Tags: java, swing, reflection, field

I am using refection to get the declared fields of a class. Now I need to select only those which are UI components, for example JLabel, JFrame, etc. Is there a way to be able to determine whether a particular type extends java.awt.Compoenent?

I did manage to get the generic type of the field, however what i need is to be able to determine whether the field extends component

Comment: `isinstance`? I guess you mean `instanceof`?

Comment: @Ademiban, sure. Just confused with python. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written an example of how to do this.
Find below the class being investigated:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class Foo {
   int i;
   long j;
   String s;
   JTable table;
   JLabel label;
   JWindow window;
 }
```

And here is the code that checks the fields of this class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Test().run();
}

private void run() {
   Class<?> c = Foo.class;
   System.out.println("The following fields extend Component: ");
   for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
      Class<?> fieldClass = f.getType();
      Class<java.awt.Component> compClass = java.awt.Component.class;      
      if (compClass.isAssignableFrom(fieldClass)) {
         System.out.println(f.getName());
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Output:

```
The following fields extend Component: 
table
label
window
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [Class#isAssignableFrom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
<Object instance>.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Component.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

yourField instanceof  java.awt.Component

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Class.isAssignableFrom()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) if you're already using reflection